# What's the Framework or Code behind this? I'd like to use it to Visualize My Data

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-interface

What's the Framework or Code behind this? I'd like to use it to Visualize My Data

https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Meh, it's a fair question (although you should specify what exactly you mean - I assume it's the "masonry" effect that sorts the sites.) Looking at the JS source, it seems to be http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Is that it? Thank you. Why the negative question for asking. Its a great UI.